# ajax.reload() table but want to keep the same page of the table instead of back to first

Tags: html, css, ajax, datatables

I have two table "table" and "status_table" , and setting every 3 second will refresh for monitor, but when I go to second  page of the table, 3 sec later will turn back to page 1, **I want to refresh the table, but also keep the page I'm on, (in table)**

[my two table screenshot](https://ibb.co/hRLYwp6) ("table" is that 6 block, and "status_table" can turn the page)

- here is the core function

```
      setInterval(function() {
      $('table').DataTable().ajax.reload();
      $('status_table').DataTable().ajax.reload();
    }, 3000);
```

and here is the template of the table [datatables.net demo](https://editor.datatables.net/examples/styling/envelopeInTable)

- and this is the full version of code if needed

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Main</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- Bootstrap 4.2.1 CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    
</head>
<body>
  

    </main> 
    <div class="m-4">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">
              <img src="assets\img\我的项目.png" height="40" alt="gyro-pic">
            </a>
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarCollapse">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
            <div class="navbar-nav">
              <a href="Main.html" class="nav-item nav-link active" style="font-family: Arial Black;">Main</a>
              <a href="IPC.html" class="nav-item nav-link" ;>E84 IPC Management</a>
              <a href="ServerManage.html" class="nav-item nav-link">Server Management</a>
              <a href="Log.html" class="nav-item nav-link" >Log Management</a>
              <a href="Alarm.html" class="nav-item nav-link">Alarm Management</a>
              <a href="AcctManage.html" class="nav-item nav-link">Account Management</a>
            </div>
    
            <div class="navbar-nav ml-auto" style="margin-top: 20px;" >
              <ul style="list-style-type: none">
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                  <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown"
                    aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    <img src="assets\img\user_icon.png" height="36" alt="gyro-pic">
                  </a>
    
                  <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                    <span style="font-family: serif; color: rgb(0, 123, 255); padding-left: 24px; font-size: 18px;">User:</span>
                    <span id="result_userid"
                      style="font-family: serif; color: rgb(0, 123, 255); font-size: 18px;"></span><br>
    
                    <script>
                      document.getElementById("result_userid").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("userid");
                    </script>
    
                    <span style="font-family: serif; color: rgb(0, 123, 255); padding-left: 24px; font-size: 18px;">Name:</span>
                    <span id="result_name"
                      style="font-family: serif; color: rgb(0, 123, 255); font-size: 18px;"></span>
                    <script>
                      document.getElementById("result_name").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("name");
                    </script>
    
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="index.html"
                    style="font-size: 16px;">Login page</a>
                  <a id="logout-link" class="dropdown-item" href="logout.html"
                    style="font-size: 16px;">Logout</a> 
                  </div>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
    

    
    <script>
      document.getElementById("logout-link").addEventListener("click", function() {
        localStorage.removeItem("token");
      });



      setInterval(function() {
      $('table').DataTable().ajax.reload();
      $('status_table').DataTable().ajax.reload();
    }, 3000);

    

    </script>
    


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.4/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
    crossorigin="anonymous"
  ></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/1.4.0/axios.min.js" integrity="sha512-uMtXmF28A2Ab/JJO2t/vYhlaa/3ahUOgj1Zf27M5rOo8/+fcTUVH0/E0ll68njmjrLqOBjXM3V9NiPFL5ywWPQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
  <!-- <script defer src="login-page.js"></script> -->

    
  <style>
    .custom-bg-orange {
      background-color: rgb(255, 119, 0);
    }

    .dataTables_wrapper {
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 30px;
  }

  .btn-reset {
        margin-right: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        width: 80px;
        height: 40px;
      }

  </style>
  
  <div id="status_table" class="m-4" style="width: 1060px; margin-left: 40px; margin-right: 20px;">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col custom-bg-orange m-3 p-3 rounded" style="color: #F0F0F0;">
        ALARM: <span id="alarm_dta">0</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col bg-danger m-3 p-3 rounded" style="color: #F0F0F0;">
        ERROR: <span id="error_dta">0</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col bg-warning m-3 p-3 rounded" style="color: #F0F0F0;">
        OFFLINE: <span id="offline_dta">0</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col bg-secondary m-3 p-3 rounded" style="color: #F0F0F0;">
        DISABLE: <span id="disable_dta">0</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col bg-primary m-3 p-3 rounded" style="color: #F0F0F0;">
        NORMAL: <span id="normal_dta">0</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col bg-success m-3 p-3 rounded" style="color: #F0F0F0;">
        TOTAL: <span id="total_dta">0</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  


  <script>$(document).ready(function() {
    const getToken = localStorage.getItem("token");
    console.log("getToken01:", getToken);
    
    var statusCounts_02; // 宣告 statusCounts_02 變數
  
    function refreshStatusTable() {
      $.ajax({
        url: "http://192.168.01.10:3000/api/item/status",
        headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + getToken
        },
        success: function(response) {
          var data = response.ipc_status;
          var statusCounts = {};
          var disableCount = 0; // 计算"ipc_enable"为false的数量
    
          for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var status = data[i].status;
            if (statusCounts[status]) {
              statusCounts[status]++;
            } else {
              statusCounts[status] = 1;
            }
    
            if (!data[i].ipc_enable) {
              disableCount++;
            }
          }
    
          console.log("Status Counts-02:", statusCounts);
    
          statusCounts_02 = Object.assign({}, statusCounts);
    
          // 更新 ALARM 的數字
          document.getElementById("alarm_dta").innerText = statusCounts_02["Alarm"] || "0";   // 要注意
    
          // 更新 ERROR 的數字
          document.getElementById("error_dta").innerText = statusCounts_02["Error"] || "0";
    
          // 更新 OFFLINE 的數字
          document.getElementById("offline_dta").innerText = statusCounts_02["Offline"] || "0";
    
          // 更新 DISABLE 的數字
          document.getElementById("disable_dta").innerText = disableCount.toString();
    
          // 更新 NORMAL 的數字
          document.getElementById("normal_dta").innerText = statusCounts_02["Normal"] || "0";
    
          // 更新 TOTAL 的數字
          var totalCount = 0;
          for (var key in statusCounts_02) {
            totalCount += parseInt(statusCounts_02[key]);
          }
          document.getElementById("total_dta").innerText = totalCount.toString();
        }
      });
    }
  
    refreshStatusTable(); // 初始加载一次数据
    setInterval(refreshStatusTable, 3000); // 每3秒刷新数据
  });
  

  </script>
  

    <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
    crossorigin="anonymous"
  ></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/1.4.0/axios.min.js" integrity="sha512-uMtXmF28A2Ab/JJO2t/vYhlaa/3ahUOgj1Zf27M5rOo8/+fcTUVH0/E0ll68njmjrLqOBjXM3V9NiPFL5ywWPQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
  


  <div id="app"></div>
  <table id="example" class="display"></table>

  <!-- JavaScript libraries -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.4/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



  <script>

var Selected_add_edit_api; // 全域變數，儲存點擊按鈕所在列的資料 


    $(document).ready(function () {
      const getToken = localStorage.getItem("token")

      console.log("GET TOKEN", getToken)

      var table = $("#example").DataTable({
        ajax: {
          url: "http://192.168.01.10:3000/api/item/status",
          headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + getToken
          },
          dataSrc: function (response) {
            console.log("DATA", response);
            return response.ipc_status
          }
        },
        columns: [
      

          {
            data: null,
            title: "ACTION",
            render: function (data, type, row) {
              return '<button class="btn btn-success delete-btn btn-reset" id="Delete_Data" data-id="' + row.device_id + '">Reset</button>';
            }
          },

          
          { data: "device_id", title: "device_id" },
          { data: "name", title: "name" },
          { data: "group", title: "group" },
          { data: "ip", title: "ip" },
          { data: "port", title: "port" },
          { data: "ipc_enable", title: "ipc_enable" },
          { data: "ftp_enable", title: "ftp_enable" },
          { data: "status", title: "status" },
          { data: "detail", title: "detail" }     

        ]
      });


      table.draw()
      // Edit row function

      var rowData; // 全域變數，儲存點擊按鈕所在列的資料
      var Reset_API_data; // 全域變數，儲存點擊按鈕所在列的資料

      $('#example tbody').on('click', 'button', function (event) {  


        var data = table.row($(this).parents('tr')).data();
        rowData = data;
  
        console.log("GET select DATA", data)   

        const { device_id, port: port_id } = data;
        Reset_API_data = { device_id, port_id };
        
        console.log("Data for Reset API", Reset_API_data)

      });

      

      $(function() {
      $('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {
        var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
        var recipient = button.data('whatever');
        var modal = $(this);
        var data = rowData;
        var inputFields = modal.find('.modal-body input');
        
        if (button.attr('id') == "AddedNew_Data02" || button.attr('id') == "AddedNew_Data" ) {        ///// 從這不一樣的，可以從這插入
          inputFields.val("");
          modal.find('.modal-title').text('Add Data ' + recipient);
          Selected_add_edit_api = "add-api";                                               //// 我試試拿這個當save() 判斷式
        } else {
          var keys = Object.keys(data);
          for (var i = 0; i < inputFields.length; i++) {
            var inputValue = data[keys[i]];
            var inputValue = rowData[keys[i]];
            modal.find('.modal-title').text('Reset' + recipient);
            Selected_add_edit_api = "edit-api";                                        //// 我試試拿這個當save() 判斷式
            $(inputFields[i]).val(inputValue);
          }
        }
      });
    });


      function editRow_website(id){
        
        var device_id=document.getElementById("device_id"+id);  
        var name=document.getElementById("name"+id);  
        var group=document.getElementById("group"+id);
        var ip=document.getElementById("ip"+id);
        var port=document.getElementById("port"+id);
        var ipc_enable=document.getElementById("ipc_enable"+id);
        var ftp_enable=document.getElementById("ftp_enable"+id);
        var status=document.getElementById("status"+id);
        var detail=document.getElementById("detail"+id);
   
        
        let getEditData = {
          "device_id": device_id,
          "email_data": name,
          "address_data": group,
          "name_data": ip,
          "email_data": port,
          "address_data": ipc_enable,
          "name_data": ftp_enable,
          "status":status,
          "detail":detail,

        }

        document.getElementById("#editid input").value = device_id
       
      }
      

      $(document).on('click', '.delete-btn', function (event) {     // 是叫delete 但 work Reset
        var id = $(this).data('id')
        
        console.log("GET Reset ID", id)

        confirmReset(id) 
      });

      function deleteData(id) {
        $.ajax({
          url: "http://192.168.01.10:3000/api/item/status/?device_id="+ id,
          type:'DELETE',
          headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + getToken  // 只要call api 要加header 的授權
          },
          success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
          }

        }).then(res => console.log("RES", res));  
      }


      function resetData(data) {

        var postData_demo = 'device_id=test--093&port_id=0'
        
        var postData = '';

        for (var key in Reset_API_data) {
          if (postData !== '') {
            postData += '&';
          }
          postData += key + '=' + Reset_API_data[key];
        }

        $.ajax({
        url: `http://192.168.01.10:3000/api/item/status/resetport?${postData}`,   /// api change ///
        type:'GET',   // get for reset
        dataType : 'json',
        contentType : 'application/json; charset=UTF-8', // 不能用 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
        data :JSON.stringify(data) , // 不用JSON.stringify()
        headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + getToken  // 只要call api 要加header 的授權
        },
        success: function(response){
          console.log("SUCCESS",response);
        },
        error:  function(response){
          console.log("ERROR",response);
        }
      })
      }


      function confirmDelete(id) {
        if (confirm("確定要delete 此 嗎？")== true) {
          var table = $("#example").DataTable();
          var row = table.row($(this).closest('tr'));
          deleteData(id);

          if (row.length > 0) {
            row.remove().draw();
            console.log("Delete row with id:", id);
          }
        } else{
          none
        }

      }
    

    function confirmReset(Reset_API_data) {
        if (confirm("確定要Reset 此 IPC 嗎？")== true) {
          var table = $("#example").DataTable();
          var row = table.row($(this).closest('tr'));
          resetData(Reset_API_data);

          if (row.length > 0) {
            row.remove().draw();
            console.log("Reset this IPC with id:", id);
          }
        } else{
          none
        }

      }
    });


  </script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>

  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">device_id:</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <form>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="input_edit_device_id" class="col-form-label">Device ID:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input_edit_device_id">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="input_edit_name" class="col-form-label">Port:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input_edit_name">
            </div>
            
            
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="save()">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <script>
    function AddRow(data) {
      const getToken = localStorage.getItem("token")
      console.log(data)
      


      // 清空輸入框的值
      $("#input_edit_device_id").val("");
      $("#input_edit_name").val("");
      $("#input_edit_data_group").val("");
      $("#input_edit_data_ip").val("");
      $("#input_edit_data_port").val("");
      $("#input_edit_data_ipc_enable").val("");
      $("#input_edit_data_status").val("");
      $("#input_edit_data_detail").val("");     
    
      $.ajax({
      url: 'http://192.168.01.10:3000/api/item/status',
      type:'POST',   // add
      dataType : 'json',
      contentType : 'application/json; charset=UTF-8', // 不能用 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
      data :JSON.stringify(data) , // 不用JSON.stringify()
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + getToken  // 只要call api 要加header 的授權
      },
      success: function(response){
        console.log("SUCCESS",response);
      },
      error:  function(response){
        console.log("ERROR",response);
      }
    });

  }




    function editRow(data) {
      const getToken = localStorage.getItem("token")

      console.log("GET TOKEN", getToken)


      //// EDIT 的api ///
      console.log("EDIT=====", data);
      $.ajax({
        url: "http://192.168.01.10:3000/api/item/status",   /// api change ///
        type:'PUT',   // aka update or edit
        dataType : 'json',
        contentType : 'application/json; charset=UTF-8', // 不能用 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
        data :JSON.stringify(data) , // 不用JSON.stringify()
        headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + getToken  // 只要call api 要加header 的授權
        },
        success: function(response){
          console.log("SUCCESS",response);
        },
        error:  function(response){
          console.log("ERROR",response);
        }
      })
      // .then(res => console.log("RES", res));  
      }
    $(function() {
        $('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
          $('.modalTextInput').val('');
          let btn = $(e.relatedTarget); // e.related here is the element that opened the modal, specifically the row button
          let id = btn.data('id'); // this is how you get the of any `data` attribute of an element
          $('.saveEdit').data('id', id); // then pass it to the button inside the modal
        })
      
        $('.saveEdit').on('click', function() {
          let id = $(this).data('id'); // the rest is just the same
          saveNote(id);
          $('#exampleModal').modal('toggle'); // this is to close the modal after clicking the modal button
        })
      })
      
      function saveNote(id) {
        let text = $('.modalTextInput').val();
        $('.recentNote').data('note', text);
        console.log($('.recentNote').data('note'));
        console.log(text + ' --> ' + id);
      }

    
    </script>

  <script>
    var storedItem = localStorage.getItem("storedItem") || [];
    
    function save() {
      var itemValue_device_id = document.getElementById("input_edit_device_id").value || "";
      var itemValue_edit_name = document.getElementById("input_edit_name").value || "";


      console.log("itemValue_device_id", itemValue_device_id, typeof(itemValue_device_id));
      console.log("itemValue_edit_name", itemValue_edit_name, typeof(itemValue_edit_name));

      let send_Reset_API_Data = {
        device_id:itemValue_device_id,
        port:itemValue_data_port,

      }
      
      if (Selected_add_edit_api === "add-api") {
      AddRow(send_Reset_API_Data); // 執行程式  AddRow
      console.log("send_Reset_API_Data", send_Reset_API_Data);


    } else {
      console.log("Invalid value for send_Reset_API_Data");
    }
  
    }
  </script>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are reloading your table, so it's normal that it will go to p.1 automatically. Every time the reload() triggers, your pagination will return to 1.